# PostgreSQL - How make simple query faster

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that is done in 600ms.
How to improve it - I'm thinking that line with date comparison is a key

```
select 
sensor_id,
sum(val) 
from tests 
where 
sensor_id in (34,35) --index on this column
and date_trunc('month', audit_date) = date_trunc('month', current_date)
group by sensor_id;
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Just to complement Lukasz Szozda answer that I find very good.

In cases you cannot modify the SQL (for any reason) it's possible in PostgreSQL to create an index with the specific column and/or column expression combination. In your case:

```
create index ix1 on tests (sensor_id, date_trunc('month', audit_date));
```

With this index in place you can use your existing SQL untouched, and get high performance.

Comment: I was going to suggest the same solution not only as a workarround but as a, in a way. "better" solution (to just this concrete problem): Despite an index over audit_date column would be more generic (so preferrable because it is more likely to be used for other queries),  an index over ` date_trunc(…)` will have much less different keys (so I guess it will be sligtly faster to traverse it, supposing it is a btree) and, more than that: having it will be used to test SINGLE equality instead of two inequalities (2 conditions, one being revense scan…).

Answer (score 4):

You could make expression `date_trunc('month', audit_date)` SARGable:

```
select 
   sensor_id,
   sum(val) 
from tests 
where sensor_id in (34,35) --index on this column
  and audit_date >= cast(date_trunc('month', current_date) as date)
  and audit_date < cast(date_trunc('month', current_date) as date)
                   + interval '1 month'
group by sensor_id;
```

And create index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON tests(sensor_id, audit_date);
```

Comment: Great. Time droped to 45 ms.